# How to retain the selected bootstrap cards border even navigated to the other page using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two html pages and each page contains 6 bootstrap cards. on click of card the card will get a border color and for every page there will be next and previous buttons when click on next the second html page will be displayed that second page will also have previous and next buttons so, on click of previous it will navigate to first page but the card that has been clicked before is not being retained with the background color but i'am getting the clicked details to the local storage 
My first.html is:

```
<div class="row">
 {% for i in room %}
 <div class="col-4"  onclick="getData({{i.id}})">
  <div class="card6 mt-3" id="main_{{i.id}}"  style ="width: 12rem;" >
   <img src="{{i.image.url}}" id = "img_{{i.id}}" alt="..." width="185" height="100">
   <div class="card-body">
    <p class="card-text" id="cont_{{i.id}}"><b>{{i.content}}</b></p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
<!--Loop ends-->
<a class="link mt-3"><u>Dont see your room?</u></a>
</p>
<div class="row mb-3">
 <div class="col-4 mr-5">
  <a href="/modsy" class="previous">&laquo; Home</a>
 </div>
 <div class="col-4 ml-5">
  <a href="/modsy/goals" class="next" id="room_next">Next &raquo;</a> </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

And JS code for on click of cards:

```
$('#main_1').click(function() {
  $(".blue").removeClass("blue");
  $(this).addClass("blue");
});
$('#main_2').click(function() {
  $(".blue").removeClass("blue");
  $(this).addClass("blue");
});
$('#main_3').click(function() {
  $(".blue").removeClass("blue");
  $(this).addClass("blue");

});
$('#main_4').click(function() {
  $(".blue").removeClass("blue");
  $(this).addClass("blue");
});
$('#main_5').click(function() {
  $(".blue").removeClass("blue");
  $(this).addClass("blue");
});
$('#main_6').click(function() {
  $(".blue").removeClass("blue");
  $(this).addClass("blue");
});
$('#main_7').click(function() {
  $(".blue").removeClass("blue");
  $(this).addClass("blue");
});
$('#main_8').click(function() {
  $(".blue").removeClass("blue");
  $(this).addClass("blue");
});
$('#main_9').click(function() {
  $(".blue").removeClass("blue");
  $(this).addClass("blue");
});
```

To get the clicked card details to local storage we will use:

```
var object= [];
function getData(id,image,content)
{
  if (object != []) {
    if (object[0] == id) {
        object = [];
    }else {
        object = []
        var id = id;
        var image= $("#img_"+id).attr('src');
        var content = $("#cont_"+id).text();
        object.push(id);
        object.push(image);
        object.push(content);
        localStorage.setItem("object", JSON.stringify(object));
  }
  }else{
    object = []
    var id = id;
    var image= $("#img_"+id).attr('src');
    var content = $("#cont_"+id).text();
    object.push(id);
    object.push(image);
    object.push(content);

  }
var storedNames = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("object"));
```

Even when navigate to the next page the local storage card details are there now i need is when I click the background color will come so even when navigate also the background color should retain for the clicked card.

Comment: There is no way to retain the card border if the browser gets refreshed. To achieve your functionality you have to create an SPA ( Single Page Application ) where when you click on the card the next page opens up in the same page without refreshing the browser. When the second page is clicked you will get your desired border color on the card.

Comment: @ Rohan my application is a wizard type

Comment: @Rohan https://www.modsy.com/project/room see this one and click next and again click previous the clicked card is retaining right i need like that

Comment: @Lakshmi. Okay I got it, just one thing - when you are click Next, does your browser gets a Post Back or a process??

Comment: no nothing just goes to next page thats it @Rohan

Comment: @Lakshmi, You can work out some CSS for this. So on click of each cards, add a class 'active' dynamically through jquery and this class will contain the border property - the way you like.  So when you click on a card, 'active' class should get attached to the class using jquery . Try this. Hope it helps.

Comment: I actually did it @Rohan see my post I wrote jquery for onclick of each card it is ok but after clicking next and when coming to back the card should retain its border like that only.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205587/discussion-between-rohan-rao-and-g-lakshmi).

Comment: @Lakshmi. I have created a simple button for you in my codepen.You can replace it with your card. I have applied css to that. See if this helps: https://codepen.io/rohan-rao-the-bashful/pen/PowQLYL

Comment: @Rohan thankyou so now in my code for main_1 I should keep this style right

Comment: Yes. Absolutely.

Comment: @Rohan I had wrote like that .blue class before but i didn't get that

Comment: Let's talk in chat.

Comment: @noobprogrammer can you help me with this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62879529/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-for-getting-data-from-a-div-onclick